# Are there any considerations I should be aware of for setting up a database with an external table reference?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design

Please don't laugh, but I'm maintaining an Access database with an external customer table for linking the local tables. I'd like to rebuild this in ASP.NET with a MySQL or SQL Server backend. I will still need to reference the external table for queries, but I've never set this up.

Is one engine better than the other for external connections? Are there any other considerations, such as security (how are the external credentials stored in each)?

Thanks for your time,

Tom

Edit: Sorry, I didn't specify. The primary database I'm linking to is an external SQL Server database, but it's on an enterprise system. The database I maintain is for one department that has access to the enterprise database, but I can't create the new tables in it.

Currently the .mdb is on a network share that is painfully slow and occasionally has issues if the single user doesn't close Access properly. I'm trying to sell them on a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only addressing the "other considerations" part of the question here:

The biggest problem I have with linked tables is from a *maintenance* programmer's perspective.  I can't tell you how often I've wasted time tracing linked tables because they were poorly documented.  I STRONGLY recommend not even going the "linked tables" route, but if you do, I would strongly recommend some way of tracking your dependencies.  (We use Blueprints from Pathway Systems for this).

There are few things worse than having to support an app made up of multiple Access databases with linked tables going back and forth.  And it's an administrative nightmare for setting permissions if not handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I may need to work that into the maintenance contract (if it breaks and it's your fault, that's extra). Fortunately, the schema of the database I link to has been consistent, or at least there haven't been changes to the two tables I reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most flexible db engine is innoDB with mysql where you can use foreing keys. This are secure as your db password is secret, no other considerations on security.

Comment: I edited my question, particularly that the database I reference is a SQL Server database. I'm looking to create an external link to two tables from a new database running the web app.